# Add TIME to DATETIME value

Tags: google-bigquery

I can see from documentation that [`DATETIME_ADD`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#datetime_add) only works with `INT64` values, not `TIME` objects.

I have a `DATETIME` which represents the point of start, and then a duration in a `TIME` object

```
WITH input AS (
  SELECT
    DATE(2018,03,05) AS start_date,
    TIME(5,0,0) AS start_time,
    TIME(8,0,0) AS duration
)

SELECT
  *,
  DATETIME(start_date,start_time) AS start_datetime,
  DATETIME_ADD(
      DATETIME_ADD(
        DATETIME_ADD(
          DATETIME(start_date,start_time), 
          INTERVAL EXTRACT(HOUR FROM duration) HOUR
        ),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM duration) MINUTE
      ),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM duration) SECOND
    ) AS end_datetime

FROM input
```

Exists a nicer way to add the 3 values of the `TIME` object (hours ,minutes ,seconds) to the given `DATETIME` object?

Comment: TIME data type is not intended to host duration rather represents a time, independent of a specific date. SO I feel like yo either have pain of doing above query or you change your design to have duration as a INT64 in whatever part of time is more relevant to your application  - like seconds, minutes, hours, etc. But as always  - there is an option that someone here will come up with nicer way so it will be less ugly thus acceptable :o)

Comment: Value is provided by federated Spreadsheet, which is filled with data of Google Form. On Google Form there is the "hour" component which allow to enter hours/minutes/second and the format is that one. An alternative should be parsing by regex the value and obtain a pure hours value, but I think it is much worse

Comment: got it. so, see my answer for `nicer way` :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
WITH input AS (
  SELECT
    DATE(2018,03,05) AS start_date,
    TIME(5,0,0) AS start_time,
    TIME(8,0,0) AS duration
)
SELECT
  *,
  DATETIME(start_date,start_time) AS start_datetime,
  DATETIME_ADD(
      DATETIME_ADD(
        DATETIME_ADD(
          DATETIME(start_date,start_time), 
          INTERVAL EXTRACT(HOUR FROM duration) HOUR
        ),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM duration) MINUTE
      ),
        INTERVAL EXTRACT(SECOND FROM duration) SECOND
    ) AS end_datetime,
    DATETIME_ADD(
      DATETIME(start_date,start_time), 
      INTERVAL DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME(start_date,duration), DATETIME(start_date), SECOND) SECOND
    ) end_datetime_nicer_way
FROM input
```